# How to send to multiple recipients (WITHOUT LOOPING) while using variable alphanumeric sender ID?

Tags: sms, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I was wondering if there is a way to set multiple recipients WITHOUT looping over the list of recipients at my end?! Also most importantly while using variable alphanumeric sender ID and NOT buying a twilio number?

I can do all this for single recipient like this:

```
$twilio_client->messages->create(
'+64*******', //to
[
    'from'=> 'foo',
    'body' => 'bar'
]);
```

Works perfectly fine. However, doesnt work with multiple receivers.

---

Also note, it was bloody-1-step easy to implement `smsbroadcast.com.au` and pass all this in a simple call (simple call, quick fast, super easy documentation - unlike twilio which has like a billion lines of confusing documentation, 200 similar products and YET no direct api to check balance, or do a simple thing such as multiple recipients!!)

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of back and through with the support, plus reading all the over-written-essay (so-called documentations), finally I found a way to get all that done.

**[Step 1: Configuration]**

You have to implement Notify product which is a separate product than the Message product.

So from left menu `Notify> Service> add New`. Here you need to add a `Messaging Service` and have it selected here for Notify.

On the **Messaging Services** page, it will ask you to buy a twilio number. Instead just click on `Configure` from the left menu and put in all the details you need.

Specifically and importantly, make sure you have `Alpha Sender ID` checked and a default Alpha Sender text entered there. This will be the default fallback in case if your api call fails to accept the `from` param.

.

**[Step 2: API Call]**

```
//$notify_service_SID = the SID from the Notify Service you added in step 1
$client = new Client($this->Account_SID, $this->auth_token);
$notify_obj = $client->notify->services($notify_service_SID);

//you need receivers in a JSON object such as the following, plus make sure numbers are starting with country code to ensure alpha sender works correctly
$receivers_json = [0=>'{"binding_type":"sms","address":"+614********"}']+[1=>'{"binding_type":"sms","address":"+614*******"}']

$call_ret = $notify_obj->notifications->create([
    'toBinding'=> $receivers_json,
    'body' => $msg, //actual message goes here
    'sms' => [
        'from'=> $sender //alphanumeric variable sender
    ],
]);
```

.

**[Step 3: Check for errors]**
There is no direct way to check all errors in twilio when implementing Notify. Here is my mixed approach.

1. Exception handling to the `notifications->create` call
2. `$call_ret` will have `err` if the Notify fails, but not when the Message fails. because Notify just passes the call to Message and there is no direct way to check Message errors over Notify call. So you would check for `$call_ret['err']`
3. Call the `Alerts` API; fetch all recent alerts, and match against the Notification SID you received from the last call.

--

Here is how to do the Alerts check:

```
$alerts = @$client->monitor->v1->alerts->read();

if(is_array($alerts))
foreach($alerts as $av)
{
    $t = @$av->toArray();
    @parse_str($t['alertText'], $alert_details);

    if(isset($alert_details['notificationSid']) && $alert_details['notificationSid'] == $call_retx['sid'])
    {
        $alert_err = $alert_details['description'];
        break;
    }
}
```

`$alert_err` will carry an error if there was an error. Apart from this there is no direct way to do it. You can fetch these Alerts via crons or you can setup a webhook for them to do a call back. Or simply implement a one call simple api that does it all in super simple way such as`smsbroadcast`.